# When to set the DropDownHeight property for an OwnerDrawVariable ComboBox

Tags: .net, winforms

In which event for a ComboBox that has a DrawMode of OwnerDrawVariable is it most appropriate to set the ComboBox's DropDownHeight?

I am currently setting the DropDownHeight value within the DrawItem event but this seems inefficient.

Edit:

The reason I ask is that I can not get the DropDown window height to be "just right". It is always a little bit too tall or too short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in the event DropDown - or override for ComboBox.OnDropDown

Comment: @AdrianToman - you accepted this as the most helpful answer, but did this really work for you? For me, setting DropDownHeight in overridden ComboBox.OnDropDown() did not work because of known WinForms bug. I needed to implement what you described in [your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5439356/2392157). OTOH setting DropDownWidth in ComboBox.OnDropDown() works well. Maybe you can consider marking the other answer as the most helpful one.

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect DropDownHeight for ComboBoxes that have DrawMode of OwnerDrawVariable is known issue that has be answered at [Unable to set the DropDownHeight of ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245530), and I have added the c# code that I use to solve my problem as part of the answer.